# How to access the get; set of a inner class after using JSON.deserialize in salesforce apex

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

So I am getting a response as jSon for which I created the class:

```
public with sharing class TurboBrigeResponse {
    public responseList responseList{get;set;}
    public String authToken{get;set;}

    public class result{
        public list<bridgeUserID> bridgeUserID{get;set;}
        public Integer totalResults{get;set;}
    }
    public class responseList{
        public list<requestItem> requestItem{get;set;}
    }
    public class bridgeUserID{
        public String notes{get;set;}
        public String name{get;set;}
        public Integer blockedFlag{get;set;}
        public Integer hostFlag{get;set;}
        public Integer excludeFromCount{get;set;}
        public String userID{get;set;}
    }
    public class requestItem{
        public result result{get;set;}
    }

}
```

Populating it via this code:

```
TurboBrigeResponse response1 = (TurboBrigeResponse)JSON.deserialize(
         string.valueOf(res.getBody()), TurboBrigeResponse.class
         );
```

Now the problem is getting the values from this list `public list<bridgeUserID> bridgeUserID{get;set;}` in my apex class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the fields of the various classes directly as you have made them public. If you want to reference an inner class name the syntax is `outer.inner`:

```
TurboBrigeResponse response1 = ...
list<TurboBrigeResponse.bridgeUserID> users = response1.userList;
if (users != null) {
    for (TurboBrigeResponse.bridgeUserID u : users) {
        System.debug('userID=' + u.userID);
        System.debug('name=' + u.name);
        ...
    }
}
```

I suggest you stick to starting class names with an upper case letter so its a bit clearer what is a class name and what is a field name. The class names never appear in the JSON.

**PS**

On new version of code:

```
for (TurboBrigeResponse.requestItem ri : response1.responseList.requestItem) {
    for (TurboBrigeResponse.bridgeUserID u : ri.result.bridgeUserID) {
        System.debug('userID=' + u.userID);
        System.debug('name=' + u.name);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I owe you a beer my friend :D